# conn.setAutoCommit(true)

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I used `conn.setAutoCommit(true);` in java, Sorry to ask this, its simple question but can't find answer on internet so asking here, How to achieve the same in asp.net c#, I am using MySql

Thankyou

Comment: what is the question and what have you tried?? show code to understand better.

Comment: r u not able to connect to MySql??

Comment: The question is the ques, It isn't neccessary to show all the code always, the question was simple. Anyway below is the answer, if the way how i asked was completely wrong then no one would have answered.

Answer (score 3):

By default database connections in .NET are set to auto-commit. If you wish to use transactions you have to call [BeginTransaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86773566.aspx).